# Publishing a ClickOnce application in TFS Team Build

Tags: tfs, msbuild, clickonce, publish

We have several `.exe` projects in our solution. What we are trying to achieve is when the project is built using TFS Team Build, we want MSBuild to create a `ClickOnce` file in the output folder. This was fairly easy to do: I simply added `Publish` to the `DefaultTargets` property of my project:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Publish;Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
...
</Project>
```

This works, however, the `ClickOnce` application is created even when the project is built locally (e.g. in `Debug` mode). Is there a way to specify a condition so that `Publish` is invoked only when the condition is true? I tried to add a a new `Target` like this:

```
<Target Condition="$(TeamBuildOutDir) != ''" Name="Publish" />
```

But this doesn't work. I believe I need additional properties in my target tag to let the `MSBuild` know that I want a `ClickOnce` target on `$(TeamBuildOutDir) != ''`, but I'm not sure how to do that. Any help is appreciated.

### Edit

I tried this (without `Condition="$(TeamBuildOutDir) != ''"`) just to see if it would work locally:

```
 <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <MSBuild
    Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"
    Targets="Publish"
     Properties="PublishDir=C:\ClickOnce"/>
 </Target>
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
There is a circular dependency in the target dependency graph involving target "AfterBuild"
```

But there is NO circular dependency in the project! The project builds just fine without this Target tag. I'm really confused.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the BuildingInsideVisualStudio property to determine when to call publish?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.package.projectfileconstants.buildinginsidevisualstudio(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I should add that the circular dependency is likely because you're calling the same project file it's building at the moment.  So you would end up in a recursive loop.